# Not getting notification?

Tags: support, notifications, comment-replies

From this morning I am not getting any notification on any comments againt my post or answers, anyone facing the issue? Problem with Stack excnhange?

I am not getting notification on below question:

[div tag increment using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530564/div-tag-increment-using-javascript)

Comment: did you get this?

Comment: @Roombatron5000 yes Now I got this. But I didnt get notification when a poster reply on my comment on stackoveflow

Comment: @imaphpdeveloper Did they comment on your post? Did they use `@`?

Comment: @Roombatron5000 Yes I got notification when you made post on my other answer.

Comment: Can you link to the comment(s) that you didn't receive a notification for, that prompted you to post this question?

Comment: @Roombatron5000 I modified my question with the link in which I didnt received notification

Comment: Since you weren't the only person to comment on that question (besides the questioner) you wouldn't receive notifications, unless the questioner pinged you (using @imaphpdeveloper).

Comment: @Roombatron5000 for you last comment You are not starting with @ imaphpdeveloper but I received notification, is it mean that I can be addressed in middle of the message also?

Comment: Since this is your post (the question) you always get notified of comments on your question. On the SO question you linked to, you were the answerer, not the questioner. So if the questioner would've commented on your post there (the answer) then you would've received notification.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 thanks for clarification.